# Replace first URL in div with second URL in div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit stuck.
I'm syndicating content and trying to undo some junk I'm inheriting. In the returned code, there are 2 URLs. The first needs to be replaced with the 2nd. Example:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pt-cv-content-item pt-cv-1-col" data-groups="category-266 category-145 category-264 category-263" data-pid="3515">
    <div class='pt-cv-ifield'>
        <a href="url-to-site-1" class="_self pt-cv-href-thumbnail pt-cv-thumb-default cvplbd" target="_self" >link text</a>
        <h4 class="pt-cv-title"><a href="url-to-site-1" class="_self cvplbd" target="_self" >link text</a></h4>
        <div class="pt-cv-content">
            <p><a href="good-link" target="_blank">good link text</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, my goal is replace "url-to-site-1" with "good-link" on the fly using jQuery.

I can output all the links in the div using a jQuery function, but I'm stuck in my efforts to replace URl1 with Url2.

Here's the jQuery that logs the URLs to the console:

```
$('.pt-cv-1-col').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

any help would be appreciated. I need a 2nd set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty simple...

```
// identify parent container
var parent = $(".pt-cv-1-col");

// determine good_href based on HTML structure
// here we want parent container's <div>.pt-cv-content's <a>
var good_href = parent.find(".pt-cv-content").find("a").attr('href');

// set all of parent's <a> href attribute to good_href we found above
parent.find("a").attr( 'href', good_href );
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/j5mvj2a3/

If you had multiples you could loop through a collection of the parents...

```
$(".pt-cv-1-col").each( function(){
    var parent = $(this);
    var good_href = parent.find(".pt-cv-content").find("a").attr('href');
    parent.find("a").attr( 'href', good_href );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j5mvj2a3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Go inverse:

1. First target the good Anchor (child of .pt-cv-content)
2. Traverse upwards using `.closest()`
3. Find all links and modify their `href`

```js
$(".pt-cv-content").find("a").attr("href", function(idx, goodHref) {
  $(this).closest(".pt-cv-1-col").find("a").attr("href", goodHref);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pt-cv-1-col">
    <div class='pt-cv-ifield'>
        <a href="url-to-site-1">link text</a>
        <h4><a href="url-to-site-1">link text</a></h4>
        <div class="pt-cv-content">
            <p><a href="good-link">good link text</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the above will work for any number of blocks in your document.